# Is it possible to have peltier plates within a few micron thickness range?

Tags: peltier

Is it possible to make peltier plates of a thickness of a few microns . If not What device/material can be used in a thickness range of a few microns for cooling purposes ?

Comment: How do you stop cold plates and hot plates thermally interfering with each other when the thickness is small.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do it but there are two problems - one theoretical and one practical.

The practical problem is in bonding the two conductive plates to the TE junctions. This is currently done by soldering, and soldering two plates with microns between them is a recipe for disaster when you get solder squeezout which shorts the micron gap.

The theoretical is addressed here http://www.tec-microsystems.com/EN/Intro_Thermoelectric_Coolers.html

> Low height pellets or/and larger pellets cross-section provide higher
>   cooling capacity value for thermoelectric cooler. In the same time
>   they increase the operating current and total power consumption. Small
>   pellets cross-section and tall pellets increase maximum temperature
>   difference and reduce TEC power consumption, but cooling capacity is
>   reduced too.

As for a process that will provide significant cooling over extremely small gaps, I'm not aware of any, but I'm not an expert. If nothing else, very short thermal paths by their nature have low thermal impedance, so it's a challenge to keep the temperature differential at desired levels, as the heat seeks to redistribute itself across the gradient.